# Best books on Daniell integral

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a second year mathematics master student . 
I would be grateful if anyone could inform me what the best books on daniell integral are , or latest article or research . 
Yours sincerely

Comment: Hope this helps you: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1967495.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check on my bookshelves resulted in the following. The treatments in **[2]** and **[3]** are relatively elementary, and **[1]** (and maybe **[4]** also) is far more comprehensive.

**[1]** Klaus Bichteler, [**Integration - A Functional Approach**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764359366)

**[2]** Angus E. Taylor, [**General Theory of Functions and Integration**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486649881) --- see Chapter 6. *Integration by the Daniell Method* (pp. 281-323)

**[3]** Adriaan C. Zaanen, [**An Introduction to the Theory of Integration**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BT7ZC) --- see Chapter 3. *Daniell Integral* (pp. 43-63)

**[4]** Adriaan C. Zaanen, [**Integration**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BR3DA) --- I don't have a copy with me now, but I believe this book has a lot of material on Daniell integration